# An alert "Invalid parameters to rollback"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, rollbacks

Why do I get an alert **Invalid parameters to rollback** when I tried to roll back the question I edited ?

Comment: Can you link to the post?

Comment: A screenshot of it as well would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer by myself.. Its approved suggested edit.. That can be the reason.

Comment: I just got this as well, and it was when I tried to rollback an approved suggested edit. Is that what you mean by "approved posts"?

Comment: @Yannis it is **approved suggested edit** .. Corrected

Comment: @RapunzelEugene How did you figure that out? I can't to find a single other source talking about this error and [it seemed to work fine before](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23331530/revisions).

Comment: [It also worked recently.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30967198/revisions)

Answer (score 5):

I did some major refactorings to the Revisions list and accidentally moved the "rollback" action outside of an edit rights check, causing it to show up for users that do not have the [2000 rep required](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

A fix is going out now.